# Rocky : How to change NFS versions from Version 4 to Version 3

Tags: mount, nfs, nfsv4

On CentOS mount command was working like:

```
mount -v -o nfsvers=3 publicip:/opt/NFSData /tmp/myshare
```

As we moved to Rocky it stopped working.

As metioned in [redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-fr/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/reference_guide/s2-nfs-client-config-options), `nfsvers=` is not supported anymore:

> - `nfsvers=2` or `nfsvers=3` — Specifies which version of the NFS protocol to use. This is useful for hosts that run multiple NFS
>   servers. If no version is specified, NFS uses the highest supported
>   version by the kernel and mount command. **This option is not supported with NFSv4 and should not be used.**

So I decided to downgrade version of NFS on Rocky as mentioned [here](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-change-NFS-and-AutoFS-versions-from-Version-4-to-Version-3-in-Flame.html), but it's not working.

Output of `nfsstat -m` before:

```
Client nfs v4: Server nfs v4:
```

Changes made in `/etc/nfsmount.conf`:

```
# Protocol Version [2,3,4]
# This defines the default protocol version which will
# be used to start the negotiation with the server.
# Defaultvers=4
Defaultvers=3
#
# Setting this option makes it mandatory the server supports the
# given version. The mount will fail if the given version is
# not support by the server.
Nfsvers=3
```

Added `insecure` flag to each share in `/etc/exports`, and ran the following commands:

```
systemctl restart nfs-server
systemctl restart rpcbind
```

After running those commands the output of `nfsstat` is same.

`mount` command output:

```
[root@ip- ~]# mount -v -o nfsvers=3 publicip:/opt/NFSData /tmp/myshare                                                                                                                                                                  
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Nov  7 08:07:24 2023                                                                                                                                                                                                        
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr='                                                                                                                                                                                        
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6                                                                                                                                                                                                              
mount.nfs: trying ip prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049                                                                                                                                                                                      
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17                                                                                                                                                                                                             
mount.nfs: trying ip prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 20048    
portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
```

Can someone please help me to understand?

output of command

lsmod |grep nfs
nfsv4                 909312  2
dns_resolver           16384  1 nfsv4
nfs                   409600  2 nfsv4
fscache               389120  1 nfs
nfsd                  544768  13
auth_rpcgss           135168  2 nfsd,rpcsec_gss_krb5
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
lockd                 126976  2 nfsd,nfs
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
sunrpc                577536  28 nfsd,nfsv4,auth_rpcgss,lockd,rpcsec_gss_krb5,nf

Comment: Well, `mount -v -o nfsvers=3 :/opt/NFSData /tmp/myshare` does not have the remote host address, although that may just be a typo on your part.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command: `lsmod |grep nfs`. Please make sure you format your additions correctly with the right markdowns as instructed in the [markdown help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Again, please notice how your should use [code block] to correctly format your question. I've already edited your question to make it more readable and was expecting you to follow my lead. The way it's written without markdowns makes it difficult to read and people will be reluctant to help you further.

Comment: It's saying it cannot find `publicip`. Start looking for that. Can you ping it? Does it resolve? Does `publicip` see the client? Perhaps the IP address for `publicip` was not copied into the local hosts file.